# Event handled in Key Handler is then being subsequently handled by Ace

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have a KeyHandler which defines a new behavior for alt up/down. After handling those keys, I call `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation`, and then return true.

For some reason that I can't figure out Ace is then handling the event after my handler. I tried setting the pos parameter of the keyhandler, which at 0 prevented it from working at all, and at 1 didn't change the behavior at all.

How do I properly tell Ace that a keyboard event is handled? Should I be using addCommand instead of KeyHandler? When should I use which, if so?

Update: code included.

```
aceEdit.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler(::keyHandler)

private fun keyHandler(data: String, hash: String, keyString: String, keyCode: Int, event: KeyboardEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 36) { //home
        this.aceEditor!!.moveCursorTo(0, 0)
    } else if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 35) { // end
        this.aceEditor!!.moveCursorTo(aceEditor!!.getValue().split("\n").size - 1, 0)
    } else if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 38) { // alt up
        moveNextOrPrev(false)
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing what exactly your code is doing. Could you create an example demonstrating the issue?.

Comment: @auser code attached. After I handle the "alt up", Ace then handles it (by swapping the position of the lines I've moved the cursor to in "moveNextOrPrev").

Comment: You did not make a working example, showing the full code, but from what is available it looks like you are not returning a command to indicate that your handler did something https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/a7412b7f924aaea7ba0f59b62e91f68fb1757e79/src/keyboard/keybinding.js#L107C1-L108C26

Comment: @auser by "a command" do you mean returning true? As mentioned in my original description I am doing that.

Answer (score -1):

keyboardHandler is not supposed to make any changes to the editor, it is supposed to return an object with either a name of an existing command, or a command object

```js
{ 
    command: string | {exec: function, ...}
}
```

This allows the editor to record macros, detect when to merge undo stack items, properly handle multiple selections, etc.

However if you can't return commands and prefer to handle key directly in keyboardHandler, you can return a special object to indicate that editor should stop calling other keyboard handlers

```js
  return {command: "null"};
```

see [keybinding.js#L107C1-L108C26](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/a7412b7f924aaea7ba0f59b62e91f68fb1757e79/src/keyboard/keybinding.js#L107C1-L108C26) for details how it is implemented.

But judging from the snippet you have provided, you don't even need to implement keyboardHandler, just adding some commands or even changing keybindings of existing commands would suffice.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got this technique originally from other (apparently misleading) StackOverflow posts. Is there documentation that describes commands? The API docs have functions but no description. What does "just adding some  commands" mean? How do I find names of existing commands? What are command objects supposed to do?